# Updating a div with text from an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm learning React and trying to create a simple div that has it's text contents update based on the contents of an input box.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

const inputId = 'input'
const containerId = 'container'

// This is the input
const input = <input id={inputId}></input>

// The contents of this should be updated
const element = <div id={containerId} children={inputId.value} />

ReactDOM.render([element, input], rootElement);
```

Currently, nothing is occuring. When you enter text in the input box. The div doesn't update. Am I missing something?

Comment: `inputId` is just a string, calling `inputId.value` will not select the element's value, if that's what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a parent component where you declare your state

```
function App() {
 const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

 return (
  <>
   <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(ev) => setText(ev.target.value)}/>
   <div>{text}</div>
  </>
 )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect from the base. Try this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

const MyApp = () => {

    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    const handleChange = () => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp/>, rootElement);
```